# Symfony3 : phpunit run from command line returns “'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.”

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I want to proceed to unit testing on my Symfony3.2 project.

But 'phpunit' command is not working : when I run phpunit, it returns **“'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.”**

Though, everything seems to be correctly set up. I searched the internet and didn't find anything.
So, could somebody help me please ?

Comment: vendor/bin/phpunit is all you need assuming you started with the usual symfony composer.json file.  The other answers deal more with installing phpunit globally.  If still not found do a composer require-dev phpunit/phpunit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link only answers are not acceptable on Stackoverflow.

Here are the steps to install on Linux:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.1.phar
chmod +x phpunit-6.1.phar
sudo mv phpunit-6.1.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
phpunit --version
```

Verify the version is shown as `6.1.x` and then from your Symfony directory you can now run:

```
phpunit
```

and your tests should run.

---

EDIT #2

Based on feedback from Cerad.
Use these commands to install on windows:

1. Make a directory C:\bin
2. Download https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.1.phar to C:\bin
3. Rename the file phpunit.phar
4. Open a command prompt and enter the following:

---

```
cd C:\bin
echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd
```

Then you can enter:

```
phpunit --version
```

and you should see the version shown. Also you need to add `C:\bin` to your environment PATH.

Comment: Judging from the error message, I'm pretty sure he is running under Windows.

Comment: You are right @Cerad. I added Windows install instructions as well.

Comment: For what it is worth I think it is just as easy to use composer to install phpunit under the vendor directory.

Comment: @Cerad, I agree with you, but I dont know why the installation with Composer didn't work :-/

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions from here:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

The new way to go as of Symfony 3.2 is to use the phpunit bridge as explained in [this blog post](http://symfony.com/blog/how-to-solve-phpunit-issues-in-symfony-3-2-applications).

Comment: Hi there @COil. The error used to occur, but looks like the PARSE_CONSTANT error has been fixed. I've experienced this previously. So installing as per Dana Danna link is the correct way to go now if you have the latest.